# How do I distinguish between traits and states using NLP?

Tags: english, semantics, computational-linguistics, adjectives

In an English sentence:

> Harry was displeased.

– *displeased* is a state

> Harry was benevolent.

– *benevolent* is a trait

Given an adjective, how can I distinguish between a trait and a state?

The more precise and unambiguous the method, the better - as I want to apply this in a computer program.

Comment: One simple method I could think of is to check whether there is an underlying verb in the lexicon, i.e. there is the verb *to displease*, but no such thing as *\* to benevol*. The idea would be that such states behave like a past perfect form of a transitive verb where the person that the adjective applies to (here: *Harry*) is the object of, i.e. *Something displeased Harry*. This obviously works only for a limited set of state adjectives (i.e. those that are regularly derived from a verb + *ed*), but might give a first hint.

Comment: Note also that a POS tagger might not assign an adjective tag to such state verbs: Depending on how elaborate it is, it might also analyse it as a past tense form in a passive construction, i.e. *Something displeased Harry* -> *Harry was displeased (by something)* in the sense of *Harry was being displeased*, which will give you different results.